# Problem generating timestamps in a loop in Bash

Tags: bash, date, while-loop, timestamp, unix-timestamp

When I run the command:

```
timestamp=$(date+"%s") ; echo "$timestamp"
```

there is no error.

However when I try to run it in a loop like:

```
while [  $COUNTER -lt 10 ]; do  ts=$(date+"%s") ; echo "$ts" ; let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 ;  done
```

"-bash: date+%s: command not found" error is thrown. Why?

Comment: Try adding space between date and arguments like this: date +"%s"

Comment: It worked thanks! Do you have an explanation on why it worked fine when the timestamp was not generated in a loop?

Comment: What OS are you using? The first example also throws an error on my mac OS system, since it's actually not the correct way to write it

Comment: @AlbertiBuonarroti Presumably, the first example is not what the OP actually runs, and not knowing the space was important, they probably didn't take care to preserve its presence in the question.

Comment: As an aside, you can get the current timestamp without needing to run an external command in `bash`. `printf -v timestamp '%(%s)T'`. In `bash` 5 or later, there is already a parameter that contains the current timestamp: `EPOCHSECONDS` or `EPOCHREALTIME`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while [  $COUNTER -lt 10 ]; do  ts=$(date +"%s") ; echo "$ts" ; let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 ;  done
```

you need to write it with a space `$(date +"%s")`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add space between date command and required format, since date syntax in linux `man` page described as:

```
date [option] [+Format]
```

Solution for your code:

```
while [  $COUNTER -lt 10 ]; do  ts=$(date +"%s") ; echo "$ts" ; let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 ;  done
```